# clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: makefile, clang, llvm

I keep getting the error

> 'error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see
> invocation)'.

I googled this error, and many people have said that 'maybe you're running out of free memory' .
My environment has 475G of free Mem and 238G of free Swap (according to free -h), so the memory doesn't seem to be a problem.
Any help would be grateful.

clang: clang-9
llvm: 9.0.0

'''

> 1 warning generated. Stack dump:
> 0.      Program arguments: /usr/local/bin/clang-9 -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free
> -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name backprop_cuda.ii -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix
> -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -coverage-notes-file /home/yunchae/personal_research/case/GPU-Sched/GPU-Sched-master/Benchmarks/rodinia_cuda_3.1/cuda/backprop/backprop_cuda.gcno
> -resource-dir /usr/local/lib/clang/9.0.0 -O1 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/yunchae/personal_research/case/GPU-Sched/GPU-Sched-master/Benchmarks/rodinia_cuda_3.1/cuda/backprop
> -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -load /home/yunchae/personal_research/case/GPU-Sched/GPU-Sched-master/build/passes/analysis/libGPUBeaconPass.so
> -faddrsig -o backprop_cuda.o -x c++-cpp-output /tmp/backprop_cuda.ii  clang-9: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault clang-9:
> error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see
> invocation) clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final) Target:
> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
> /usr/local/bin clang-9: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug
> report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace,
> preprocessed source, and associated run script. clang-9: note:
> diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s) - no
> preprocessable inputs. Makefile:37: recipe for target
> 'backprop_cuda.o' failed make: *** [backprop_cuda.o] Error 254 '''

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4soEW.png)

Comment: 475 **gig** if free memory?  238 **gig** of swap?  That seems unlikely--are you sure that's right?  If it is true, that seems like a problematic system configuration (have you considered how that system would run if it was using _200G_ of swap space?  Is your swap on some kind of NVRAM or something?)

Comment: The system I'm using is a server provided by our lab.

Comment: Added a screenshot. (output of free -h)